# I want to delete users' messages, but it deletes all users

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is my firebase realtime database.

[image]

I want to delete the "completes" tab .but the code is deleting all users. not working properly.where did i go wrong.
the code I use

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: 'https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/'
});


/**
 * @function HTTP trigger that, when triggered by a request, checks every message of the database to delete the expired ones.
 * @type {HttpsFunction}
 */
exports.removeOldMessages = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const timeNow = Date.now();
    const usersRef = admin.database().ref('/users');
    usersRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            if ((Number(child.val()['complete'])) <= timeNow) {
                child.ref.set(null);
            }
        });
    });
    return res.status(200).end();
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to delete the 'completes' tab "? There is no notion of `complete` in your code.

Comment: I typed wrong. I fixed it now.

Comment: "if ((Number(child.val()['complete'])) <= timeNow) {"           here

Comment: I think you should do `child.ref.child('complete').set(null);` instead of `child.ref.set(null);`

Answer (score 0):

**André's comment above shown you how to delete the `complete` node, and not its parent.**

However, your Cloud Function code doesn't take into account the fact that you need to wait for the asynchronous tasks (all the calls to [`set(null)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set), which returns a Promise that "resolves when the write to server is complete") to finish before you send back the response with `return res.status(200).end();`.

If you don't do that, your Cloud Function might finish **before** the asynchronous tasks are done (and some `complete` nodes might not be deleted). You will find some detailed explanations in the first 2 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

So, since you need to wait that all the Promises returned by the asynchronous `set()` tasks resolve, you need to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and adapt your code as follows:

```
exports.removeOldMessages = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const timeNow = Date.now();
    const usersRef = admin.database().ref('/users');

    usersRef.once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
        const promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            if ((Number(child.val()['complete'])) <= timeNow) {
                promises.push(child.ref.child('complete').set(null));
            }
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .then(results => {
        return res.status(200).end();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        //Watch the official video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA
    })
});
```